# Google Charts Table displaying incorrect date

Tags: google-visualization

[In this example](https://jsfiddle.net/3vn7unv0/) google charts table is given a date of 1/1/16 and displays 12/31/15.  Do I need to use some kind of timezone or something?

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart', 'table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'dt'); 
  data.addRows([[new Date("2016-01-01")]]);
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart'));
  table.draw(data);
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I see Jan 1, 2016 in your example.

Comment: Added a screenshot, confirmed on another computer and on my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not related to google-visualization, the real answer is here...
[Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/5090771)

use format such as `'01/01/2016'` to get expected results...