# Google stacked bar chart with date on x and time on y

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

Im trying to create a Google stacked bar chart with time on the y-axis and date on x - axis, with no success.

Ex: for 2012-05-01 i want a bar that goes from 00:00 to 24:00.

I have been able to create a simple stacked bar chart like this.

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria', 'Denmark', 'Greece'],
    ['2003',  1336060,    400361,    1001582,   997974],
    ['2004',  1538156,    366849,    1119450,   941795],
    ['2005',  1576579,    440514,    993360,    930593],
    ['2006',  1600652,    434552,    1004163,   897127],
    ['2007',  1968113,    393032,    979198,    1080887],
    ['2008',  1901067,    517206,    916965,    1056036]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: "Year"},
            hAxis: {title: "Cups"},
            isStacked: true}
      );
}
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is something like this

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('timeofday','Starttime');
data.addColumn('timeofday','Endtime');

data.addRows{
['2015-01-01','Funtime',[13,0,0],[16,0,0],
['2015-01-01','Boringtime',[16,0,0],[19,0,0],
['2015-01-02','Sleeptime',[1,0,0],[5,0,0],
}
```

The result of this would be two bars. At 2015-01-01 with two events one starting from 13:00 to 16:00 (in the y-axis) and on top of that another from 16:00 to 19:00. On 2015-01-02 there would also be one event from 1:00 to 5:00.

Am I able to do this with Google Bar charts?

Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

there are a few problems in your code, you can check the browser's console for these errors

**1.**
the [`addRows`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addRows) method takes an array `[]` of rows,
and should be called with parenthesis `()` not curly braces `{}`

within the array, there should be another array for each row
the rows from the example are not complete and are missing the final bracket `]`
`['2015-01-01','Funtime',[13,0,0],[16,0,0],`
should be
`['2015-01-01','Funtime',[13,0,0],[16,0,0]],`

**2.**
the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#data-format) does not allow a `string` column, after the first column
`'Funtime'` will have to go...

**3.**
if using type `'date'` for the first column, then need actual date objects in the data
if --> `data.addColumn('date', 'Date');`
use --> `[new Date('01/01/2016'), [13,0,0], [3,0,0]],`

or a `'string'` column can be used for the first column as well
if --> `data.addColumn('string', 'Date');`
use --> `['2015-01-01', [13,0,0], [3,0,0]],`

**4.**
notice the date format used in this example --> `'01/01/2016'`
using `'2016-01-01'` with actual dates will result in problems such as these...
[Google Charts Table displaying incorrect date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38333195/5090771)
[How do I align date and values to gridlines in Google Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32133792/5090771)

**5.**
finally, if you want *time on the y-axis and date on x - axis*
use `ColumnChart` instead of `BarChart`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('timeofday','Starttime');
    data.addColumn('timeofday','Endtime');
    data.addRows([
      [new Date('01/01/2016'), [13,0,0], [3,0,0]],
      [new Date('01/02/2016'), [16,0,0], [3,0,0]],
      [new Date('01/03/2016'), [1,0,0], [4,0,0]]
    ]);

    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {
      height: 600,
      isStacked: true,
      vAxis: {
        format: 'HH:mm',
        viewWindow: {
          min: [0,0,0],
          max: [24,0,0]
        }
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , please take a look the the next answer. Posted it as a answer instead of a comment because the text was long. Appreciate the help!